# Why is BaseEncoding marked as unstable in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm writing the following code:

```
BaseEncoding.base64().encode(byteArrayEntity.getBytes())
```

But the Intellij (Community 2018.2) is showing the bellow warning:

```
'BaseEncoding' is marked unstable
Inspection info: Reports unstable API (elements annotated with one of annotations from list) usages.
```

I don't know if it's something I should worry about. Could someone explain?

I thank the attention...

Comment: It's `com.google.common.io` right? What version of guava do you have. I have 19 and it doesnt show a warning on `BaseEncoding`.

Comment: Thank you @vikingsteve, you comment helped me... :)

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Google GitHub API BaseEncoding is marked as "Beta", so it might function perfectly fine. But if I where you I'd still use java.util.Base64 since I never encountered any problems with it.

This should deliver just the same result:

```
java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteArrayEntity.getBytes());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I learned one more...
I updated the version of guava to 27.0-jre and already solved.